# EasyAPNS can't connect to database

Tags: php, iphone, sql, ios, ipad

I am using Easy APNS to connect to a MySQL database on my server. In their instruction video, in the log when running the app, you are not supposed to receive any return data, or at least the guy didn't and his device shows up in his database while mine doesn't. Here is my log, does anyone have any idea why that number would be showing up (can't connect, database is messed up, can't find a file, etc.)? Thanks!

```
//Log

Register URL: http://www.chillysky.com/push/apns.php?task=register&appname=Carillons&appversion=1.0&deviceuid=b2149150466465779f14a03634d2aefa7b216256&devicetoken=7eeeaa4195cf69d896e9d3b31d09db4143d7759d8e36e22a3d7c8ff4c83a4d23&devicename=Jackh's%2520iPad&devicemodel=iPad&deviceversion=4.3.3&pushbadge=enabled&pushalert=enabled&pushsound=enabled
2011-08-10 21:50:38.410 Carillons[533:607] **Return Data: <436f6e6e 65637420 6661696c 65643a20 4e6f2073 75636820 66696c65 206f7220 64697265 63746f72 790a5468 65726520 7365656d 7320746f 20686176 65206265 656e2061 20736c69 67687420 70726f62 6c656d20 77697468 206f7572 20646174 61626173 652c2070 6c656173 65207472 79206167 61696e20 6c617465 722e3c62 72202f3e 3c627220 2f3e0a3c 74657874 61726561 20726f77 733d2231 30222063 6f6c733d 22383022 3e4d7953 514c2045 72726f72 3a0a0a0a 34320a0a 4572726f 723a200a 4572726f 7220233a 200a4669 6c656e61 6d653a20 7777772e 6368696c 6c79736b 792e636f 6d2f7075 73682f61 706e732e 7068703f 7461736b 3d726567 69737465 72266170 706e616d 653d4361 72696c6c 6f6e7326 61707076 65727369 6f6e3d31 2e302664 65766963 65756964 3d623231 34393135 30343636 34363537 37396631 34613033 36333464 32616566 61376232 31363235 36266465 76696365 746f6b65 6e3d3765 65656161 34313935 63663639 64383936 65396433 62333164 30396462 34313433 64373735 39643865 33366532 32613364 37633866 66346338 33613464 32332664 65766963 656e616d 653d4a61 636b6827 73253235 32306950 61642664 65766963 656d6f64 656c3d69 50616426 64657669 63657665 7273696f 6e3d342e 332e3326 70757368 62616467 653d656e 61626c65 64267075 7368616c 6572743d 656e6162 6c656426 70757368 736f756e 643d656e 61626c65 640a3c2f 74657874 61726561 3e>**


//Code for return data


NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"Register URL: %@", url);
NSLog(@"Return Data: %@", returnData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just accessing the URL in your post gives the following result when used in a browser

Connect failed: No such file or directory There seems to have been a slight problem with our database, please try again later.

Looks to me that there is still an issue with the config of the mysql part within the APN script.

EasyAPN also expects all certificates to be there (both development and production). What I found easiest was to get the scripts working first by doing all things from within Terminal till all errors were resolved before trying anything from within my application.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll look at the script to make sure everything is good, and then I'll test it in Terminal. Thanks!